# there was a problem running the requested app expo ios

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an expo app and started it in production mode using `expo start --no-dev --minify` on my laptop. I logged in to my expo client android app and successfully ran the app.
I want to test it on iphone so I asked a friend to login to expo-client with my credentials and run the app. He can see the running project under recently in tab but on clicking it he gets this error:

```
there was a problem running the requested app
```

Do the devices have to be on same network to run the app?

Answer (score 0):

> Do the devices have to be on same network to run the app?

Yes, to run an app on expo, is highly recommended to be on the same network to avoid this kind of error.

Actually, your friend don't need your credentials to launch the app. Just send him your QR Code or a SMS link.

Just take a look at the resolution of QR Code. If it's 192.X.X.X. it will be certainly a local IP address and it will be not accessible by someone on another network.

Comment: So I tried both the ways and it didn't work. Seems like the devices have to be on same network. I have to publish the project and then open in expo-client if on different networks.